# Model validation on Popup Login form

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I stuck here  need help
Ruby on rails
I have one Pop-up for login it is coming when i click on link "Sign in" using jquery 
Now i want to validate username and password entered by user from database 
Login popup is a partial page sign in.html.erb
any solutions. plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on which validation framework you are using.

the key is to keep the dialog not closed once server responses.

(NOT RECOMMENDED) if you are not using any javascript validation framework, you have to make the "form" a "remote form", then submit it, then display the error messages if validation failed.

(MY EXPERIENCE) if you are using an javascript validation framework such as RSV(really simple validation), just define the validation rules, then implement 2 ajax methods: 1 is used for validating the form, another is a callback function used to process the response from remote and display it in the dialog.

anyway, dealing with the error message for a dialog is not very easy and straightforward than dealing with it for a regular page.  Anyway, I hope you got my idea.

Comment: Thanx Siwei i got it but i have to make this login pop-up as remote only because, i have to call this form everytime when user tries to access restricted page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my login partial which i have render and also validate it.

```
   <div class="clost_holder"> <%= link_to image_tag("/assets/close-new.png"), "javascript:;", :onclick => "close_popup()" %>

</div>

<%= form_for(@user, :as => @user, :url => session_path(@user), :html => {:id => 'sign_in_form', :onsubmit => "return false;"}) do |f| %>
    <div class="login_input_holder mtop20 flt">
      <label>Email</label>

      <p><%= link_to 'dont have an account ?', :controller => 'devise/registrations', :action => 'new' %></p>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="login_input_holder mtop10 flt">
      <label>Password</label>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="fogot_password "><%= link_to 'forgot password ?', :controller => 'devise/passwords', :action => 'new' %></div>
    <div class="login_btn frt"><input type="submit" value="signin" id='sign_in_btn'></div>


<% end %>
```

And then validate it.But you need to add jquery.validate and jquery.form files also.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">


     $("#sign_in_btn").click(function() {

      if (!jQuery("#sign_in_form").valid()) {

          return false;

      }
    else {

        var container = $("#home1_content");

        $("#sign_in_form").submit(function() {

            $(this).unbind('submit').ajaxSubmit({

                success: function(data) {

                    container.html(data);

                     window.location.reload();

                }
            })



        });

    }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sign_in_form").validate({
        rules:{
            "user[email]":
            {
                required: true ,
                email: true
            },

            "user[password]":
            {
                required: true
            },
            messages: {
                "user[email]": "This field is required",
                "user[password]": "This field is required"
            }
        }
    });
});


     </script>
```